# NUnit Could not load file or assembly 'LogAnalyzer

Tags: nunit

Hi I just started to read [The Art of Unit Testing: With Examples in .Net](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) in order to understand what unit testing is and how to properly code unit tests.

First I tought that in the book the author is going to use the integrated Unit Testing Tools from Visual Studio witch I assumed is called NUnit.I was wrong but it was no problem because the principles of unit testing should be the same in both (correct me if I am wrong)

I tryed installing NUnit on my PC witch has isntalled an x64 Windows 8.This is the code I am trying to test:

```
 public class LogAnalyzer {
    public bool IsValidLogFileName(string fileName) {
        if (!fileName.EndsWith(".slf")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is the code that does the testing:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LogAnalyzerTests {
    [Test]
    public void IsValidFileName_validFileLowerCased_ReturnsTrue() {
        LogAnalyzer analyzer = new LogAnalyzer();
        bool result = analyzer.IsValidLogFileName("whatever.slf");
        Assert.IsTrue(result, "filename should be valid");
    }
}
```

When I try to load the dll of the test in  NUnit GUI and run it I get the following error:

```
LogAnalyzerTests.LogAnalyzerTests.IsValidFileName_validFileLowerCased_ReturnsTrue:
```

System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'LogAnalyzer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

This are the steps I followed after installing NUnit:

1. create class project
2. add reference to the project that is tested
3. add reference to NUnit
4. Open NUnit GUI
5. Load NUnitClassLibrarry.dll from debug folder
6. Run (this is where the error appeared)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my curent problem aldo I do no fully understand why this works.In the folder where NUnit is installed there is an x86 version of the program and for some reason this one works.